# can't generalize regex expression

Tags: regex

I am writing a regex expression to reduct some data from my logs.

so I wrote a few Python lines

```
import re

text = ",\\\"authorization\\\":\\\"Bearer xxxxxx.yyyyy.fff-dddd\\\","
match = re.search(r"authorization\\\":\\\"([^\\\"]+)", text)

if match:
    authorization_string = match.group(1)
    print(authorization_string)


text = ",\\\"authorization\\\":\\\"xxxxxx.yyyyy.fff-dddd\\\","
match = re.search(r"authorization\\\":\\\"([^\\\"]+)", text)

if match:
    authorization_string = match.group(1)
    print(authorization_string)
```

The output of this is what I need, i.e.

```
Bearer xxxxxx.yyyyy.fff-dddd
xxxxxx.yyyyy.fff-dddd
```

If I try in [regex](https://regex101.com/r/evH1H3/1) does not seem to work

If I use

https://regex101.com/r/R7Oz9J/1

manage to grab one case, but I would like to find an expression that is able to grab the token even if the string "Bearer " is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get both cases that you specified working with the following:

```bash
/"authorization\\\\\\\":\\\\\\"(.+)\\\\\\"/gm
```

You can see the working example [here](https://regex101.com/r/vVabTa/1).